# Vue - How to access Elements from B-table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using a **"b-table"** with **":fields"** and **":items"**, I already know how to customize specific fields with **"v-slot:cell(keyname)"**. 
But know I want to get the value of each element in this column and display it differently depending on its value. Is there a way to do this?

My table looks like this

```
        <b-table
                striped hover
                responsive
                :fields="shotlist_tab.fields"
                :items="shotlist_tab.shots">

            <template v-slot:cell(frame)>
                <!-- ACCESS ELEMENT -->
                <div v-if="???">
                    <font-awesome-icon class="icon" :icon="['fas', 'image']"/>
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                    <img src="../../assets/logo.png" height="50" width="50" alt="frame"/>
                </div>
```

I have already create a standard table with `v-for="(object, index) in objects"` where I can access each data with `object.element`
I want to replicate this with the b-table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slots are scoped, meaning you are passed the cells value, along with additional information (i.e. the entire row data, the field definition for the cell, etc).

```html
<template v-slot:cell(frame)="scope">
  <!-- You may need to adjust the condition/check for your situation -->
  <div v-if="scope.value === null">
    <font-awesome-icon class="icon" :icon="['fas', 'image']"/>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <img src="../../assets/logo.png" height="50" width="50" alt="frame"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Refer to the docs for custom data rendering at: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#custom-data-rendering